# Raising manipulation touch events (e.g. swipe, pinch, rotate) at the windows 11 OS level

Tags: python, winapi, touch, pywin32, pyautogui

I would like to *raise* certain touch events at specific locations on the screen in windows 11. Ideally I'd do this through python or something python can bind to easily. I don't want to *handle* touch events, and I don't want to raise them *within and application*. Ideally there would be an API so I could `swipe(start,stop)` or `pinch_in(center,edges,speed)` or something like that.

Looking through some of the windows documentation I see that there is an API for `DirectManipulation` which looks a bit like what I'm looking for. Here's the windows 32 API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/directmanipulation/ne-directmanipulation-directmanipulation_interaction_type

For instance there is an enum called `DIRECTMANIPULATION_INTERACTION_TYPE` where I could set the value to `DIRECTMANIPULATION_INTERACTION_TYPE_GESTURE_PINCH_ZOOM` for a certain kind of event. But I'm unsure how to raise these events to the OS. I tried to poke around at the directmanipulation.dll but that didn't immediately help.

Is there a well practiced way to raise touch events to the OS from within python?

Comment: [`InjectTouchInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injecttouchinput). I'm not aware of a way to generate higher-level gestures, though.

Comment: [Simulating Touch Input in Windows 8 Using Touch Injection API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6460.simulating-touch-input-in-windows-8-using-touch-injection-api.aspx?PageIndex=2) explains how to build gestures on top of raw touch input.